# Stripping quotes from response and transferring to request endpoint

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI for testing some REST api. As a response I'm getting the URL that should be an endpoint of the next request.

I made the following Property Transfer step

```
source : myApiCall
property : response

target : myHttpCall
property : endpoint
```

Everything would be ok, but when transferred the endpoint looks like "www.myurl.com" (with quotes) and thus is invalid. How do I strip the quotes from there?

Raw response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 98
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 09:04:28 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 09:04:28 GMT

"http://myurl.com/query?queryUid=90e97bdb-00a3-47c2-8809-c15ceec6ea1b"
```

Comment: It works correctly for me, can you share the xml response and the `XPath` or `JSONPath` operation you're using? maybe the problem is there.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the raw response. I have nothing in the transfer properties step, just the source/property and target/property as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your *Raw* response include the `"` quotes in the String. Then you've two possible solutions, remove the `"` from the *Raw* response and keep using the same property transfer.

Or if you can not change the response then you can use a *Groovy* script testStep to get the *Raw* response and manipulated it to remove the additional `"` quotes before set the endpoint:

```java
// get your api call
def myApiCall = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('myApiCall')
// get the raw response
def responseUrl = myApiCall.getPropertyValue('Response')
// since your response contains the `"` remove it
responseUrl = responseUrl.replace('"','')
// set the endpoint correctly
def httpCall = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('myHttpCall')
httpCall.setPropertyValue("endpoint",responseUrl)
```